# JQuery Highlight Row and Column in table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to add to my site table with highlighting row and column, but I have troubles with
column highlighting. This is my table. This is online courses and a full the table with
names such as Homework1, HW2 and etc.

```html
%if len(students) > 0:
   <div class="grades">
     <table class="grade-table">
     <%
     templateSummary = students[0]['grade_summary']
     %>
    <thead>
       <tr class = "table-header"> <!— Header Row —>
          %for section in templateSummary['section_breakdown']:
             //......
             <th title="${tooltip_str}"><div class="assignment-label">${section['label']}</div></th>
          %endfor
        <th title="${_('Total')}"><div class="assignment-label">${_('Total')}</div></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <%def name="percent_data(fraction, label)">
    //....
      <td class="${data_class}" data-percent="${fraction}" title="${label}">${ "{0:.0f}".format( 100 *       fraction ) }</td>
    </%def>

    <tbody>
       %for student in students:
          <tr class="table-row">
              %for section in student['grade_summary']['section_breakdown']:
                  ${percent_data( section['percent'], section['detail'] )}
              %endfor
             ${percent_data( student['grade_summary']['percent'], _('Total'))}
         </tr>
       %endfor
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

This is JQuery. So in highlightRow() is making the magic with row, but I don't understand,
to add highlightColumn() and "$element.find('tr').bind('mouseover', highlightColumn);" or
to add in the function highlightRow() code for column.

```js
var Gradebook = function($element) {
    "use strict";
    var $body = $('body');
    var $grades = $element.find('.grades');
    var $studentTable = $element.find('.student-table');
    var $gradeTable = $element.find('.grade-table');
    var $search = $element.find('.student-search-field');
    var $leftShadow = $('<div class="left-shadow"></div>');
    var $rightShadow = $('<div class="right-shadow"></div>');
    var tableHeight = $gradeTable.height();
    var maxScroll = $gradeTable.width() - $grades.width();

    var mouseOrigin;
    var tableOrigin;

    var startDrag = function(e) {
       mouseOrigin = e.pageX;
       tableOrigin = $gradeTable.position().left;
       $body.addClass('no-select');
       $body.bind('mousemove', onDragTable);
       $body.bind('mouseup', stopDrag);
    };
    
    var highlightRow = function() {
         $element.find('.highlight').removeClass('highlight');

         var index = $(this).index();

         $studentTable.find('tr').eq(index + 1).addClass('highlight');
         $gradeTable.find('tr').eq(index + 1).addClass('highlight');
    };
    
    $leftShadow.css('height', tableHeight + 'px');
    $grades.append($leftShadow).append($rightShadow);
    setShadows(0);
    $grades.css('height', tableHeight);
    $gradeTable.bind('mousedown', startDrag);
    $element.find('tr').bind('mouseover', highlightRow);
    $search.bind('keyup', filter);
    $(window).bind('resize', onResizeTable);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this:

```
$element.find('td').bind('mouseover', highlightColumn);

var highlightColumn = function() {
     //remove all highlights
     //not sure if it should be here may be it should happen before both highlightRow and highlightColumn function calls
     $element.find('.highlight').removeClass('highlight');

     var columnIndex = $(this).index(); //this should be td in this case

     $studentTable.find('tr td:eq(' + columnIndex + ')').addClass('highlight');
     $gradeTable.find('tr td:eq(' + columnIndex + ')').addClass('highlight');
};
```